# Difference between 'later' and 'later on'

Tags: differences, idioms, adverbs

Is there any difference between the usage of 'later' and 'later on'?

> - I'll see you **later**.
> - I'll finish it **later on**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say the addition of the word “on” is more or less superfluous in almost every case. In other words,  I believe *later* can always be substituted for *later on*, but not the other way around. When in doubt,  *later* is the safe word to use.

For example,

> We will have lunch now, and later on(or later) we will go to the park.

Where you can’t use *later on*:

> I arrived later than she did.
>
> See you later.

*Later* can be a way of saying goodbye, as a short form of “see you later”, but you can’t use “later on” in this way. *Later* and *later on* can both be thought of as short terms for “later on in time”.

Comment: "Later on" is usually used when talking about a more distant future:
• I call you later [today]
• I call you later on [next week] 
"Later on" can be substituted with "later", but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary just gives it as a synonym of the adverb "later", but to me there feels to be an expressive difference, at least sometimes. I *think* it has a connotation of including the hearer in whatever is going to happen. So in

```
When are you going to look at this?

Later.
```

or
    Later on.

the reply "Later on" seems less brusque, and more conciliatory. But it is a very subtle difference.

Comment: I think there *can* be an "expressive difference", as you call it. @Terry doesn't expand on it, but to me his example encapsulates what I mean. It seems to me adding "on" is more likely when "later [on]" means relative to some specific activity/event already introduced into the discourse. If "later" is simply being used to reference a future time relative to *now*, the word "on" is less likely to be added.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, a hanging preposition.  Occasionally "later on" may have a cadence that complements the rest of a sentence, but I see this as redundant language similar to "advocating for" rather than simply "advocating" (in most uses).

Comment: It's not a preposition, it's an adverb, and it's not "hanging". It may be redundant, but I think it has a prosodic and possible affective function which I'm still thinking about.